# Matched leaf route at location "/home" does not have an element or Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I keep getting the error "Matched leaf route at location "/home" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page." when attempting to route to different screens.
App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import React from "react";
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import Sleep from './Screens/Sleep';
import Brew from './Screens/Brew';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Steam from './Screens/Steam';

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/sleep" component={<Sleep />} />
          <Route path="/brew" component={<Brew />} />
          <Route path="/steam" component={<Steam />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.js, Bottom tab navigation used to route between screens

```
    

import React from 'react';
import { Nav, NavItem } from 'reactstrap'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch, faHome, faUserCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const tabs = [{
  route: "/home",
  icon: faHome,
  label: "Home"
},{
  route: "/sleep",
  icon: faSearch,
  label: "Sleep"
},{
  route: "/brew",
  icon: faUserCircle,
  label: "Brew"
},{
  route: "/steam",
  icon: faUserCircle,
  label: "Steam"
}]

const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Bottom Tab Navigator*/}
      <nav className="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light" role="navigation">
        <Nav className="w-100">
          <div className=" d-flex flex-row justify-content-around w-100">
            {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
              <NavItem key={`tab-${index}`}>
                <NavLink to={tab.route} className="nav-link bottom-nav-link" activeClassName="active">
                  <div className="row d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon size="lg" icon={tab.icon} />
                    <div className="bottom-tab-label">{tab.label}</div>
                  </div>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Nav>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Navigation;
```

I have tried multiple solutions that I have found but none of them have worked yet. I have a feeling it has something to do with me mixing multiple code snippets I have found and attempting to put them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `react-router@6` `Route` component uses an `element` prop taking a `ReactNode` (*e.g. JSX*) or `Component` prop taking a React `Element`.

See `Route` [`element`/`Component`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#elementcomponent).

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}/>
    <Route path="/sleep" element={<Sleep />} />
    <Route path="/brew" element={<Brew />} />
    <Route path="/steam" element={<Steam />}/>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/home" Component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/sleep" Component={Sleep} />
    <Route path="/brew" Component={Brew} />
    <Route path="/steam" Component={Steam}/>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

> ### Important
>
> You should only opt into the `Component` API for data routes via
> `RouterProvider`. Using this API on a `<Route>` inside `<Routes>` will
> de-optimize React's ability to reuse the created element across
> renders.

So in other words, don't do the second example above since it is a de-optimization.